# How to avoid warning of Unreachable code

Tags: c#

I have the below

```
string currency = string.Empty;
Regex r = new Regex(@"~(\w*[a-zA-Z0-9$£~%]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
for (Match m = r.Match(expression); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
      currency = (m.Groups[1].Value);
      break;
}
return currency;
```

The intension is that, after the first match in the loop it should break.

The warning messge(Unreachable code) is happening  **m = m.NextMatch()** of the loop.

How to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is currently broken, basically. You're really never going to execute `m = m.NextMatch()`, so why have it?

I think you want:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"~(\w*[a-zA-Z0-9$£~%]+)",
                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

Match m = r.Match(expression);
string currency = m.Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : "";
```

Personally I think this is rather clearer, in terms of what the final version of "currency" is.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why are you even using a loop here? Why not just use r.Match(expression) straight off?

There's little point of having a loop if you'll always break out of it on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 'break;' wihout any condition. This will cause the loop to brak on the very first time. So, incremental part 'm = m.NextMatch()' won't execute even a single time, for which you are getting the warning. Try to use an if condition like as follows:

```
If(currency<0){break;}
```

Use the proper condition for which you want the 'break' to happen. That should help you just fine.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The general rule on how to avoid warning about unreachable code, is to not write unreachable code.

Let's take a look at what you've written:

1. A loop
2. For each entry in the loop, extract the value of a group, then break the loop
3. Go to next, err.. no, we'll never get here

The entire loop is unnecessary.

Instead, this would suffice:

```
string currency = string.Empty;
Regex r = new Regex(@"~(\w*[a-zA-Z0-9$£~%]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
Match m = r.Match(expression);
if (m.Success)
    currency = (m.Groups[1].Value);
return currency;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use m = m.NextMatch()
if the expression is matched you will get the same iterating the groups. so modify the code for scanning the groups for your desired values.